# How to pass a string from one JFrame To an existing JFrame

Tags: java, string, jframe

I have two jFrames **Form_1** and **Form_2**.

here is the **Form_1**:

[image: Form_1]

and Here is the **Form_2**:

[image: Form_2]

What I already did is, the **Form_2** will run first and when I press ***"Open Form 1"*** button, it will open the Form_1.

Now, what I want to do is, when I enter a text in **Form_1 Text Box** and press ***"Show in Form_2"***, the **Form_1** will close and show the text in **Form_2 Text Box**.

I have tried this:

```
private void Form_1ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      String form1_text = form1textbox.getText();
      Form_2 form2 = new Form_2();
      form2.form2textbox.setText(form1_text);
      form2.setVisible(true);
      this.setVisible(false);
}
```

It works but it opens a new **Form_2** and shows the text in it. How can I show the text in the **existing Form_2** without opening a new one? Please help me.

Comment: You could simply close your Form_2 when You call the Form_1.After that When You call the Form_2 just use your implemented method

Comment: You can achieve this by using interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to open Frame_1 from Frame_2 just pass the object of Frame_2 to the Frame_1.

In Frame_2

```
Frame_1 from1 = new Frame_1(this);
```

Where in Frame_1 constructor is looks like this

```
Frame_2 form2;
public Frame_1(Frame_2 fr2){
   form2=fr2;
}
```

Now in Frame_1 work with form2

```
String form1_text = form1textbox.getText();
form2.form2textbox.setText(form1_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create and initialize your Form_2 object and hide it immediately the main method (form2.setVisible(false)). Then, when you want to show it, update the text box object like you already have, and just call form2.setVisible(true).

Comment: Basically, calling `new Form_2()` automatically creates the window, so do not call that method again. Just use the swing visibility controls.

Comment: I can do it but I need to do it without hiding the Form_2. So, is the any way to it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Form_2 wouldn't be hidden if you set the visibility to true. Is the problem that you cannot hide the window at any point in the program? And if so, why? You are doing the same with Form_1.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Form_2 instance global so that it can be accessed by `Form_1ButtonActionPerformed.`

```
public class MyClass{
    public static Form_2 form2;

    public void someMethod(){
        form2 = new Form_2();
        ...
    }
    ...
}

private void Form_1ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String form1_text = form1textbox.getText();
    MyClass.form2.form2textbox.setText(form1_text);
    form2.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}
```